# Multiple threads created for single Task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I helped create a background task system for an ASP.NET web site.

This is my root `Task`

```
Task.Factory.RunNew(RunTimer);
```

This is called from the root `Task`.

```
private void RunTimer() 
{ 
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) 
    { 
        var backgroundTasks = _tasks.Values.ToArray(); 
        var tplTasks = new List<Task>(); 
        foreach (var backgroundTask in backgroundTasks) 
        { 
            var newTask = new Task(() => backgroundTask.Run()); 
            tplTasks.Add(newTask); 
            newTask.Start(); 
        } 
        Task.WaitAll(tplTasks.ToArray()); 
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfSecondsToWait && 
            !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested; i++)
        { 
            Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

`_tasks` is a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, IBackgroundTask>`. For what ever reason, `newTask` is executed 2 times on separate threads -- namely `backgroundTask.Run()` is called twice. `RunTimer` is only called once. `NumberOfSecondsToWait` is 60. I've verified that `tplTasks` only has 2 items in it.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: What is the problem? Seems to me backgroundTask.Run() will be called for every task in _tasks. Also for the sleep you should use: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(NumberOfSecondsToWait * 1000)

Comment: it creates 2 threads. i'm trying to stop it at its earliest convenience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because lambdas (in particular, the `newTask` lambda) bind to variables, not values.

You need:

```
...
foreach (var backgroundTask in backgroundTasks)
{
  var localBackgroundTask = backgroundTask;
  var newTask = new Task(() => localBackgroundTask.Run());
  ...
}
...
```

Comment: Yes, another variation of the captured loop-var.

Comment: +1 Another good explanation here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/parallelextensions/thread/14df8a19-d58e-4303-82ad-ab9c62bdff81

Comment: FYI, tools like reSharper will help keep you from doing this sort of thing.